# Wifi details using Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I want to fetch all the details of connected wifi such as SSID, IP, Mac add and the most important thing is signal strength of connected wifi.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/wifi

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**

You can try [connectivity](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity) for SSID, IP, and wifi name. It works in both and ios. Code example

```
var wifiBSSID = await (Connectivity().getWifiBSSID());
var wifiIP = await (Connectivity().getWifiIP());network
var wifiName = await (Connectivity().getWifiName());wifi network
```

**Method 2**

Ftech ipAddress, routerIp, dns1, dns2, bssId, ssid, macAddress, linkSpeed,signalStrength frequency, networkId, connectionType you can use [wifi_info_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/wifi_info_plugin#-readme-tab-)

For example,

```
Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
WifiInfoWrapper wifiObject;
// Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
try {
  wifiObject = await  WifiInfoPlugin.wifiDetails;
  //print wifi details here
}
on PlatformException{

}
}
```

**Warning: Method 2 only works in android only**

Comment: First plugin is only used to check internet connection while the other plugin is not updated since 2020 which makes it incompatible with new fltter especially if your app is null safe.